# pandas alternative to append change dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

since `pd.append` is deprecated, I've migrated in my code all my `df = df.append(temp)`  to `df = pd.concat([df, temp])`

Usually, I have processing where I do something like:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(columns=['some', 'cols'])
for _, temp in df.groupby('key'):
    # SOME PROCESSING OF temp df like
    # temp = pd.merge(out, temp, on=['some', 'cols'])
    out = pd.concat([out, temp]) # before: out = out.append(temp)
```

Here, since out is an empty df at first but columns are set, it will not keep dtypes from the temp df. For instance, if I have a datetime column, it's converted as object.
If I use an empty df without columns, it keeps the dtypes.

Is that expected ? Considering append will be deprecated this has huge impact in all my code.

Comment: "Usually, I have processing where I do something like:..." Just so you know, that is an antipattern. Don't repeatedly use concatenation to build a dataframe... First build a list then concatenate the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

First create a list of DataFrames that you want to concat and then concat them. This should fix the problem of default data type of empty DataFrame as the data type will be determined by the non-empty elements in the list.

Multiple concatenation is giving me float64 datatype.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [], 'b': []})
for i in range(5):
    temp = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2]})
    df = pd.concat([df, temp])
print(df.dtypes)
```

Single concatenation is giving me int64 datatype.

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = []
for i in range(5):
    temp = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2]})
    df_list.append(temp)
df = pd.concat(df_list)
print(df.dtypes)
```